# Will adding more fields to the mongo query makes it faster or slower?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume that I have a mongodb collection **books**.

```
[{book_id: 124, book_name: 'ABCD', language: 'English'}, {book_id: 185, book_name: 'EFGH', language: 'French'}, ...]
```

**book_id** is unique. So to retrieve a specific book, only **book_id** is enough.
The query may be

```
db.books.find({book_id: 124})
```

Suppose I also know that the book is an 'English' book. I can make the query to

```
db.books.find({book_id:124, language: 'English'})
```

Will adding more fields, which are not necessary, to the query makes it faster or slower?

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer is adding more fields definitely slower the query.

But in your situation as you mentioned precisely book_id is unique and you know the book is an English language book, it doesn't make any difference to query.

What matter here is book_id is indexed or not?

MongoDB indexes works in a linear way:
Suppose book_id is neither indexed nor unique. In that case a collection scan will return assume 100 docs contains book_id:124 and then out of 100 it will look for how many fields contains language as English.

But if book_id is indexed then query will use index scan and directly return 100 doc and look for language as English.

If both book_id and language are part of compound index in that case your query only return that particular documents.